# eclipse + Subversion: File is out of date

Tags: eclipse, svn

i have a little problem with eclipse and SVN/Subversion.

Before i'm start to develop, i'm update the Source (each time) - Ok, Standard if you want to be up to date ;-)

but after finish my work, on commit the subversion server says every time that the file is to old.

Smart example. i have only changed a simple line:
[image: eclipse and subversion]

I can do what I want - The problem always occurs every 1-2 days. Merge **won't** work, revert + update **won't** work,.. provisionally i'm delete the complete project from eclipse and fetch it new, than i have no problems until it occurs again after 1-2 days again.

But i can't not constantly re-create the project, so I have not had the thought with Subversion.

Can someone give me tips on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was the SVN-Connector. Have installed a other version, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one developer on shared codebase ("trunk-only development"), they work in parallel and independently, they can change the same file simultaneously and "fist commit win all": others **must** update own WCs and integrate foreign changes before commit will be possible

Your screenshot clearly show it: while you changed one line, comparing with remote detect 2 different strings (7 and 9)

You have to update, as suggested, or have better communication in team in order to prevent conflicts, or move to branch-based development

Comment: i'm currently working alone on these repositorys. I have 5 Repos for various client/server implementations (HTML5, Java-Applet, Chatserver, iOS-App and Android-App). A friend working only on the Android-Repo. Its not an communication problem of "the Team". Im misunderstand that the repo says "the file is to old" although I previously updated the complete project